# Is it possible to recreate no-blending mode by only using glBlendEquation and glBlendFunc?

Tags: opengl

I want to transfer an alpha-enabled image from one texture to another.  If I do it without any preparations, the image fades out, as it will be using alpha for blending twice.  On the other hand, if I call `glDisable(GL_BLEND)` prior to transferring the image data, everything works perfectly.

Let's say, for some reason, calling `glEnable`/`glDisable` pair is discouraged in my rendering engine, but I still can invoke `glBlendFunc` or `glBlendEquation`. With that said, how can I achieve the same blending mode wherein destination texel just get assigned from its source counterpart?

Comment: Why would glEnable/glDisable be discouraged? Sounds a lot like a homework problem to me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably overthinking this. The blend function for his case is simply:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ZERO);
```

This will multiply the source with 1, and the destination with 0, meaning that you only use the source.

If you changed the blend equation from its default, you also have to reset it to:

```
glBlendEquation(GL_FUNC_ADD);
```